# Can parallel calls slow down a profiler?

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, profiling

I was tasked to find out what's making part of an application I was assigned to so slow. I decided to give the trial of Redgate's **Ants Profiler** a go. When running it, the majority of hot spots were contained with loops that the original developer wrote as `Parallel.For()` loops.

Just to see what effect it would have, I replaced them with standard for-loops, and the profiler sped up by several seconds. However, testing without a profiler, using a simple `DateTime.Now` difference between the start and end of one such loop, shows that the `Parallel.For()` loop is more than twice as fast.

Is it possible that running the code through the profiler creates an artificial bottleneck when trying to use the Parallel class?

Comment: The main purpose of a profiler is to find slowness bugs, not to be fast.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I realize this. The problem is that the program runs faster one with with the profiler, and slower without, creating a discrepancy that's dependent on the tool being used and not the bottlenecks in the code itself. It's like a false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when doing parallel things, the profiler samples all threads which makes the normal profiler performance drop be bigger with more threads.

Comment: News to me. I'll keep that in mind when looking at the profiler results in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @KChaloux You may also want to make sure you are using less invasive Profiling Modes: if you do not necessarily need to see line-level times then switch to Method-level; if you only need to see you rown source code then set the appropriate profiling mode too.